# Converting String to values in hashmap

Tags: java, arrays, string, for-loop, hashmap

I'm working on a program that reads in a string and then converts each character of that string into a number based on its value in the hashmap.

Just like a telephone number. What I'm having trouble with is the logic behind it, I can't seem to get it work.

What I'm doing is converting the string to a char array and then iterating over it and grabbing the first character. Then I find the key in the hashmap corresponding to the letter and get the value of it. I add this value to my empty word (this will build up the new string).

Can't seem to get it to work, been working on it for a while. Thanks for help.

Hashmap values: mapped as

```
public static void setUpHashmap(){
    lettersToNumbers.put("abc", '2');
    lettersToNumbers.put("def", '3');
    lettersToNumbers.put("ghi", '4');
    lettersToNumbers.put("jkl", '5');
    lettersToNumbers.put("mno", '6');
    lettersToNumbers.put("pqrs", '7');
    lettersToNumbers.put("tuv", '8');
    lettersToNumbers.put("wxyz", '9');
}
```

Code:

```
public static String convertCharStringToNumbers(String str){
    char[] stringArray = str.toCharArray();
    String word = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray.length; i++){
        char letter = stringArray[i];
        if (lettersToNumbers.containsKey(letter)){
            word+=lettersToNumbers.get(letter);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word.toString());
    return word;

}
```

Comment: You'd be better off with a `HashMap<Character,Integer>`, and put each entry in separately, like `lettersToNumbers.put('a', 2)` and so on.  You could even write a separate method that iterates through the characters in a `String`, putting them individually in the map.

Comment: You have String as key in your HashMap but you are giving a character as input to your get method in the HashMap.

Comment: @magna_nz One thing i dont understand is how r u comparing a single character with a "abc" String like key? Shouldn't the keys be a single character too?

Comment: Also what is your input into the program is it a telephone number string or a name?

Answer (score 0):

Your way: Iterate through the Hashmap keys(Eek)

```
for(String key : lettersToNumbers.keySet()) {
    if(key.contains(String.valueOf(stringArray[i])){
      //Do what you want
    }
}
```

Better way:  O(1) lookups(The whole point of using Hashmaps?)

Put characters as key in the hashmap and do lookups.

Comment: So I should make the hashmap as <Character, Integer> and map every single key in the alphabet to the integer value?

Comment: Yes, basically. So when you do a look up character by character you dont have to iterate through the map again and directly find it

Answer (score 0):

Quick and diRty hacK))

```
static HashMap<String,Character> lettersToNumbers = new HashMap<String, Character>();

public static String convertCharStringToNumbers(String str){
    String[] stringArray = str.split("(?!^)");
    String word = "";
    for (String letter : stringArray) {
        for (String s : lettersToNumbers.keySet()) {
            if (s.contains(String.valueOf(letter))) {
                word += lettersToNumbers.get(s);
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word.toString());
    return word;

}

public static void setUpHashmap(){
    lettersToNumbers.put("abc", '2');
    lettersToNumbers.put("def", '3');
    lettersToNumbers.put("ghi", '4');
    lettersToNumbers.put("jkl", '5');
    lettersToNumbers.put("mno", '6');
    lettersToNumbers.put("pqrs", '7');
    lettersToNumbers.put("tuv", '8');
    lettersToNumbers.put("wxyz", '9');
}
```

OR

```
static HashMap<Character, Integer> lettersToNumbers = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

public static String convertCharStringToNumbers(String str){
    char[] stringArray = str.toCharArray();
    String word = "";
    for (char letter : stringArray) {
        if (lettersToNumbers.containsKey(letter)) {
            word += lettersToNumbers.get(letter);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(word.toString());
    return word;

}

public static void setUpHashMap(){
    for (int i=97, t = 2; i<121; i+=3, t++){
        lettersToNumbers.put((char)i, t);
        lettersToNumbers.put((char)(i+1), t);
        lettersToNumbers.put((char)(i+2), t);
    }
    lettersToNumbers.put((char)(122), 9);
}
```

if abc == 1, then t = 1 or if abc == 2 (how in my telephone) then t = 2.

Comment: Kind of ruins the point of having a `HashMap` don't you think?

Comment: @DavidWallace What you think about second solution?

Comment: So you're giving two solutions now? Maybe you should post them as two separate answers, so that people can vote on them separately. For example, I may wish to upvote one and downvote the other.  But in answer to your question - what do I think about the second solution - I think it's a bit horrible. It's rather convoluted. It's unclear what  `i` is  and what `t` is - so longer variable names would have been better.  You've also used numbers where you should have used  character literals. And I don't believe it handles `"PQRS"` all sharing the same number, so it probably gives the wrong answer.

Comment: @DavidWallace The question contains lowercase letters. Obviously that a uppercase letters this code will not work. If I understand you right. Can you give right solution?

Comment: No, my point is that your solution assigns the same number to  `s` as to `t` and `u`; not the same number as `p`, `q` and `r`.  I understand that the question is about lower case letters.

Comment: @DavidWallace you right. I did not notice that on the key 7 is worth 4 letters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are entering a string in your program say "xyzuuabc" then the program prints out the corresponding mapped numbers "47855213".

```
String name = "";

    Map<Character, String> lettersToNumbers = new HashMap<Character, String>();
    lettersToNumbers.put('a', "2");
    lettersToNumbers.put('x', "4");
    lettersToNumbers.put('u', "5");
    lettersToNumbers.put('b', "1");
    lettersToNumbers.put('c', "3");
    lettersToNumbers.put('y', "7");
    lettersToNumbers.put('z', "8");

    String enteredString = "xyzuuabc";
    char[] splitNum = enteredString.toCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < splitNum.length; i++) {
        if (lettersToNumbers.containsKey(splitNum[i])) {
            name += lettersToNumbers.get(splitNum[i]);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your set contains entries like ("abc",2), yet everytime you call the function convertCharStringToNumber, you are checking if the map contains one character at a time, so if the string sent in is "atq", you are checking for the keys a, t, and q.  Yet, none of these keys exist in the map that you have created.  If instead that map looked like:

```
  lettersToNumbers.put("a",2);
  lettersToNumbers.put("b",2");
  lettersToNumbers.put("c",2";
  //continue for the rest of the alphabet
```

Then the keys would actually be contained in the map.